# Feeding the output of two functions to another function Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, input, composition

I have three functions.

```
function1 :: [Person] -> [String]

function2 :: String -> [Person] -> [(String, Int)]

function3 :: [String] -> [(String, Int)] -> [String]
```

I want the output of `function1` and `function2` to be passed to `function3`.
E.g `function3(function1 function2)`

But `function1` and `function2` both have their own parameters so it'd look something like:

```
function3(function1([Person]) function2(String [Person]))
```

I've looked at function composition but that's when you feed the output of one function to another. In this case, I want to feed the output of two separate functions to another.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need parentheses on your function calls. `f (g h)` means f applied to a single argument which is `g h`. You probably want `function3 (function1 ...) (function2 ...)` where `...` is the arguments to each function.